# How to disable Firefox from jumping to last window position on startup?

Tags: firefox

When Firefox starts (Linux, FF 50.1.0), the window opens up in a default location, then a second later it jumps to the location it was before the application closed.

Is there a way to prevent the window from moving to its previous location when Firefox starts up?

I remember it was possible to do this in `about:config`, but I forgotten the exact key name that I had to change.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple sources online will tell you to set `privacy.resistFingerprinting` to `true`, but that didn't work for me.

The issue is actually more deep-seated than you might think:
With many thanks to [this reddit post](https://old.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/17i0n25/permanently_lock_window_position_xulstorejson/k8jf7bt/), I will restate the core takeaways from it here:

- Firefox possibly stores the last window position in `xulstore.json` in the profile directory, but deleting that doesn't help (which I can personally confirm as well).
- Additionally, firefox *also* stores the last window position in `sessionstore.jsonlz4`, which is harder to edit due to being compressed in a non-standard format.

Now for the actual solution that has worked for me so far (I've been repeatedly testing it for a few minutes).
Use the following script to start firefox:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

config_dir="$HOME/.mozilla/firefox" # <-- set this to where your firefox config directory is (it's probably already correct)
profile_name="main" # <-- set this to your profile folder name, which you can find out by going to about:profiles

cd "$config_dir/$profile_name"

# for good measure (there shouldn't be anything meaningful in there anyway)
rm xulstore.json

[ -e sessionstore.jsonlz4 ] && {
    t=`mktemp` \
    && cat sessionstore.jsonlz4 | jsonlz4tool d | jq 'del(.windows.[].screenX) | del(.windows.[].screenY)' | jsonlz4tool c >"$t" \
    && cp "$t" sessionstore.jsonlz4
}

firefox "$@"
```

You will need to have [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) and [`jsonlz4tool`](https://codeberg.org/T0mstone/jsonlz4tool) installed.
The latter is a tool I wrote myself that can compress and decompress `.jsonlz4` files (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1363747/how-to-decode-decipher-mozilla-firefox-proprietary-jsonlz4-format-sessionstor/1363751#1363751) for more details). You can probably also make it work with [`dejsonlz4`](https://github.com/avih/dejsonlz4), but I haven't tried it.