# How to decode/decipher Mozilla Firefox proprietary .jsonlz4 format? (sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4)

Tags: firefox, backup, json, session-restore

I'm trying to get a handle on Mozilla Firefox's proprietary file format `.jsonlz4`, used, for example, for `sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4`, but to no avail.

How do I get back my data, specifically, some long text I've typed in some textareas of a crashed session?  It's my data!

Comment: I wouldn't call the format _proprietary_. Granted, it's custom, not used anywhere outside Mozilla projects, but since the whole of Firefox—including the relevant (de)compression code—is free and open source, this format shouldn't be called proprietary. (P.S. I'm not talking of the branding, which is licensed differently.)

Comment: @Ruslan, but it is in fact proprietary — just because it's OSS doesn't make it non-proprietary, as there are zero standard tools to look into the content of these files, whereas all other files, even Java's JAR format, can easily be managed with 100% standard non-proprietary tools that are available in ports/packages of every decent UNIX system.  OTOH, it is completely non-trivial to actually get back your own data from these `.jsonlz4` files.

Comment: JsonLZ4 was a bad idea.

Comment: I'd agree with "it's custom, not proprietary".  Irrespective of it not being widely used or supported.  Proprietary means owns exclusive rights to.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As per https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/2ps6wg/jsonlz4_bookmark_backups/, the following appears to work most reliably:

- in `about:config`, toggle the `devtools.chrome.enabled` setting from the default of `false` to a value of `true`
- open **Scratchpad** from within Firefox:

  - either with <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> on a MacBook,
  - or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>,
  - or through the menu bar through **Tools** → **Web Developer** → **Scratchpad**
- in the menu bar within ***Scratchpad*** of Firefox, change **Environment** from **Content** to **Browser** (omitting this step would subsequently result in errors like `Exception: ReferenceError: OS is not defined` at the next step)
- use code like the following within the ***Scratchpad*** of Firefox:

  ```js
  var file = "/Users/…/sessionstore-backups/recovery.baklz4";
  //OS.File.read(file, { compression: "lz4" }).then(bytes => 
  //  OS.File.writeAtomic(file + ".uncompressed", bytes));

  OS.File.read(file, { compression: "lz4" }).then(bytes => {
    OS.File.writeAtomic(file + ".uncompressed.stringify",
      JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(bytes)), null, 1))
  });
  ```

  The final parameter to [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) handles how many spaces would be used at each line; putting 0 causes the whole thing to be printed on a single line, putting 1 splits the lines properly (putting 2 would create too much useless whitespace and increases the size of the file for little benefit)
- click the **Run** button
- run `fgrep :textarea /Users/…/sessionstore-backups/recovery.baklz4.uncompressed.stringify` from within the **Terminal** app

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in FF 72 on Linux. Scratchpad has been removed, but the Console now supports multi-line mode. However, the `OS.File.read(...` line gives : "ReferenceError: OS is not defined".

Comment: @mivk that error is mentioned above — happens due to wrong environment; is there no way to chance the environment?

Comment: I have not found this "Environment" setting or anything similar in FF 72.0.1.

Comment: Hi this still works, but instead of the Scratchpad, you need to use the Web Developer Browser Console:

    Menu --> Web Developer --> Browser Console

Then hit "Ctrl + B" or click the icon to enable the multi-line editor and then the script above still works.

Verified with firefox 87 on Ubuntu 21.04.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Deprecated_tools

Comment: It works on newer versions as @TillKolditz says, if you open the Browser Console directly from the menu or keyboard shortcut.
But it _doesn't_ work if you open Tools --> Browser Tools --> Web Developer Tools from the menu (or Ctrl+Shift+I) and click the Console tab at the top: then it gives the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: OS is not defined".

Comment: ... but this no longer works for me in FF 108.0.1.  @Wyrme's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1749889/1109070) says that OS has been replaced with IOUtils and provides new code.

Answer (score 28):

Unfortunately, due to a non-standard header, standard tools won't work. There's [an open proposal](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209390) to change that. Apparently the Mozilla header was devised before a standard lz4 frame format existed; it does wrap a standard lz4 block.

That said, the [same bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209390) includes a few alternative methods. I'll list them briefly:

- Use the [dejsonlz4](https://github.com/avih/dejsonlz4) tool, which [includes binary builds](https://github.com/avih/dejsonlz4/releases) for Windows and should be easy to build on *nix

  - [lz4json](https://github.com/andikleen/lz4json) is a similar tool, but relies on an external liblz4 and is somewhat easier to build on *nix but harder on Windows (outside WSL)
- Use this fairly simple Python script: https://gist.github.com/Tblue/62ff47bef7f894e92ed5 (requires the lz4 package via pip or your package manager) -- the script appears to be python3 but is trivially adaptable to python2
- There is a [webextension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozlz4-edit/) available that should be able to open these. NB: while [source](https://github.com/serj-kzv/mozlz4-edit) is available, I have not verified it, and the permissions it requests are a bit concerning ([especially the response to concerns](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozlz4-edit/reviews/1081483/))
- In theory, you should be able to strip the first 8 bytes (e.g. with `dd if=original.jsonlz4 of=stripped.lz4 bs=8 skip=1`) and that should leave you with a valid lz4 block. Note that this is distinct from a lz4 *frame*. While most programming languages have libraries that can easily decode a block, finding a prebuilt tool to do so is more difficult, e.g. the `liblz4-tool` package only accepts the frame format.

Comment: BTW, here's the lz4json that compiles cleanly on UNIX®, Mac OS X, MacOS, FreeBSD, OpenBSD and NetBSD — https://github.com/cnst/lz4json.

Comment: Good explanation.  It would be nice to have some kind of reference as to how to add back the missing lz4 _frame_ (after stripping the leading 8 bytes) so as to be able to use the commonly available lz4 utility to do the decompression.  Unfortunately, it seems this must be somewhat difficult to do or someone would already have done it.  Something like `{ echo 0x184D2204 | xxd -r ; tail -c+9 previous.jsonlz4 ; } | lz4 -dc` (which doesn't work).

Comment: @jrw32982 At a minimum you'd also need a [frame descriptor](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/doc/lz4_Frame_format.md#frame-descriptor). But you'll run into another problem: the standard lz4 frame format has rather limited block sizes (4 MB max uncompressed size in the current version). Seems it's intended to support one frame with many smaller blocks, rather than one big block as the Mozilla format uses.

Comment: The Python gist for me worked great. It was also short enough to read to see it wasn't doing something horrible to my system, unlike the other options, some of which were native programs that needed to be compiled.

Comment: There's a debian/ubuntu package `lz4json` of https://github.com/andikleen/lz4json in the standard repositories now

Answer (score 13):

I found the following methods to be working, testing on Ubuntu 20.04:

### Method 1: Using the mozlz4 binary from GitHub:

Download the linux binary for mozlz4 from https://github.com/jusw85/mozlz4.
Then run the following:

```
chmod u+x mozlz4-linux

./mozlz4-linux -x filename.jsonlz4
```

### Method 2: Using the lz4json package from Ubuntu repos:

Ubuntu 20.04 repos have a package named lz4json.
I haven't checked whether it is present on previous Ubuntu versions.

To install and use that, run

```
sudo apt install lz4 lz4json

lz4jsoncat ~/.mozilla/firefox/*default*/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4
```

The above output will show a minified json.
To make it readable, you can use the 'jq' json parser:

```
sudo apt install jq

# then pipe the output of the previous command through jq to make it readable:
lz4jsoncat ~/.mozilla/firefox/*default*/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4 | jq
```

If you just want to see the list of URLs and the page titles, you can use this:

```
lz4jsoncat ~/.mozilla/firefox/*default*/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4 \
  | jq '.["windows"] | .[0] | .["tabs"] | .[] | .["entries"] | .[0] | .url,.title' \
  | grep -v 'New Tab' | grep -v 'about:newtab' | sed 's/"http/\n"http/g'
```

Comment: I used repos, it works, have not checked completeness (that all tabs are there), but output of that long pipe looks promising: `"https://www.quora.com/How-does-multi-threading-in-a-uni-processor-work"
"(1) How does multi-threading in a uni-processor work? - Quora"`

Comment: Would be great to expand the answer adding how to add links back to Firefox.

Answer (score 8):

The [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1363748/1742635) no longer works for me, on version 106 of firefox.

Scratchpad is replaced by Browser Console, and OS.File has been replaced with IOUtils: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/dom/ioutils_migration.html

Here are updated steps:

- In about:config, toggle the devtools.chrome.enabled setting from the default of false to a value of true
- Open **Browser Console** inside firefox:

  - On windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
  - Or through the toolbar through **Tools** → **Browser Tools** → **Browser Console**
- In the console you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to enter multiline mode
- Use code like this in the console:

```js
let file = '/Users/…/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4';
let data = await IOUtils.readJSON(file, { decompress: true });
IOUtils.writeJSON(file + '.uncompressed', data);
// alternately for pretty printing
IOUtils.writeUTF8(file + '.uncompressed.pretty', JSON.stringify(data, null, 1));
```

- Click the **Run** button
- run `fgrep :textarea /Users/…/sessionstore-backups/recovery.baklz4.uncompressed.stringify` from within the **Terminal** app

Answer (score 6):

I was able to extract the URLs from the **{profile-dir}/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4** file using the following free online tool designed expressly for this purpose:

https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/scrounger.html

The same site offers a similar tool for decrypting **jsonlz4** files from the **{profile-dir}/bookmarkbackups** directory.

Comment: Also just found this, works flawless.

Comment: Crashes when trying load huge (10000kB+) files

Answer (score 4):

On [UNIX® and UNIX-like systems](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/559365/28354), like Mac OS X with MacPorts, FreeBSD, OpenBSD or NetBSD with pkgsrc, the following https://github.com/cnst/lz4json fork of lz4json could also be used to compile cleanly out of the box, e.g., on Mac OS X w/ MacPorts:

```
sudo port install lz4
git clone https://github.com/cnst/lz4json.git
cd lz4json
make
./lz4jsoncat ~/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/CHANGE\
THIS.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4 \
| python -m json.tool | fgrep :textarea | more
```

Answer (score 3):

The Python script from @Bob's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1363751) is broken with latest python3 lz4 lib, but it can be fixed if you replace

```python
import lz4
```

with

```python
import lz4.block as lz4
```

Answer (score 0):

This website can convert the file to readable JSON.

https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/bookbackreader.html

No data is sent to the server, it's all done client-side.

Answer (score 0):

From within Firefox 123, the solution of @wyrme doesn't work any more. I got it following way:

1. Set the `devtools.chrome.enabled` preference to *true* in about:config ([source](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_console/index.html))
2. Open Parent Browser Console (Ctrl-Shift-J)
3. Execute following code:

   ```
   let file = '/home/…/sessionstore-backups/recovery.baklz4'
   let fileu = file+'.uncompressed'
   let utf8 = await IOUtils.readUTF8(file, { decompress: true });
   let x = await IOUtils.writeUTF8(fileu, utf8);
   ```

   This should return the number of decompressed bytes
4. Set back `devtools.chrome.enabled`

Extra hint: If it's about session restore, it is probably better to make this from a clean profile, so start firefox --ProfileManager.